# Better understanding what big O is referring to

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I thought I understood big-O notation relatively well, but now I'm not sure. In particular, I've seen several posts like [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/why-is-the-discrete-logarithm-problem-assumed-to-be-hard) discussing how the discrete logarithm problem is (probably) hard since our best algorithms are exponential in terms of number of bits.

If I understand correctly, to find an $x$ given an integer $y$, generator $g$ and prime $p$ s.t 
$$g^x \equiv y\ \mod{p}$$
would require at most $O(p)$ trials. But if $p$ is $k$ bits then the run time is actually $O(2^k)$.

I'm struggling to understand why we decided to express the runtime in number of bits. For example, sorting can be done in $O(n\log n)$ time where $n$ is the number of elements in an array-like structure. Well $n$ also has $k$ bits, so that means the runtime is $O(k*2^k)$; sorting is exponential? I'm clearly missing something, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write it in terms of the number of bits because it accurately models the reality of how computers work.
Computers don't natively support addition of arbitrarily sized numbers in 1 time step. Instead, they break such operations into addition of constantly-sized numbers (say bits for simplicity), and then use these as a basis for some algorithm to add larger numbers. Essentially, to measure the time complexity of some algorithm, we need to state what operations "cost" 1 time step, and any choice we make should be informed by how computers are built in practice.

---

You're also slightly misunderstanding the complexity of sorting. Things like quicksort state that you can sort an $n$-element array using $O(n\log n)$ *comparisons*. But how much does each comparison cost? If all elements in the array are assumed to be constant-sized, this is $O(1)$, so the overall time complexity is $O(n\log n)$.

But what if the size of elements in the array grows with the overall array? If you have an array of $n$ elements, each of which is an $n$-bit number, quicksort still works in $O(n\log n)$ comparisons. How much does each comparison cost though? In terms of bit operations, it should be $O(n)$ time. So one has that the complexity of sorting this array is:
$$
O(n\log n) \text{ comparisons} \times O(n) \frac{\text{time}}{\text{comparison}} = O(n^2\log n)\text{ time}
$$
So sorting this array is actually $O(n^2\log n)$ time.

In your example, you're right that it takes $O(p)$ trials. If $p$ is $2^k$ bits, why should this be "exponential"?
Consider the *very basic* part of your algorithm, which is setting some counter $i = 0$, and incrementing it all the way up to $p$. How many *bit operations* does this simple part of the algorithm take? While this sounds like a dumb question, actually designing an algorithm and evaluating its cost (in terms of *bit operations*) may be useful for your understanding.

Comment: Actually, saying an array with $n$ elements and each has n-bit is confusing the complexity. One can prefer an array with $n$ elements each at most $k$-bit. The $k$ and $n$ are not related to each other, in general. Therefore $\mathcal{O}( n k \log n)$ is better to express.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity is measured in the size of the input. For a list with $n$ elements, input size is $O(n)$.

The input to a discrete log or factoring algorithm has size equal to the number of its bits.